# I can not show a variable in the TextView in android after trying many ways

Tags: android, android-intent, textview

I am building a circle area calculator but for some reason I can't display any text in the `TextView`...I tried to solve it by a couple of ways but it still never displayed the answer in the `TextView`... My last try was using a similar way like Google's messages app training
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Here is my first `Activity`:

```java
public class CircleActivity extends Activity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.circle_activity);
    }

    public void hhh(View view) {
        EditText radius = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.radius);
        Double radiusdb   = Double.valueOf(radius.getText().toString());

        Intent myintent = new           Intent(CircleActivity.this,CircleResult.class); 
        myintent.putExtra("I", radiusdb);
        startActivity(myintent);
    }
}
```

and this is the second `Activity` where the `TextView` is:

```java
public class CircleResult extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void meth7(){
        Double RESULT = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("I");
        Double x = RESULT + 1;
        Double FINAL = x * x * 22/7;

        TextView FCR = new TextView(this);//CREATING the textview FinalCircleResult

        String h = String.valueOf(FINAL);

        setContentView(FCR);
        FCR.setTextSize(45);
        FCR.setText(h);
    }
}
```

I don't know were exactly the problem is, anyway, thanks for your help.

here is my xml layout for circle result activity

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

      <TextView
      android:id="@+id/FCR"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="41dp" />

      </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you add a log in both activities? for Double RESULT and for Double radiusdb.

Comment: Did you debug in order to find out you get the right value from the EditText?

Comment: I tried the app in my phone and on an emulator but neither gave me a result

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your function is not get called anywhere, check out my comments below!

```
public class CircleResult extends Activity{
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // function not get called anywhere!!!    
    meth7();
 }

 /**
  * the code of meth7() is actual dead as is not running, being called,
  * anywhere in your activity
  */
 public void meth7(){
   Double RESULT = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("I");
   Double x = RESULT + 1;
   Double FINAL = x * x * 22/7;

   TextView FCR = new TextView(this);//CREATING the textview FinalCircleResult

   String h = String.valueOf(FINAL);

   setContentView(FCR);
   FCR.setTextSize(45);
   FCR.setText(h);

 }

}
```

Comment: actually I set these methods to run on click with a button so it must work fine

Comment: tried your way but it gave me a force close when opening circle activity activity

Comment: it is not displaying the answer

Comment: I spent a whole day trying to figure out what's the problem

Comment: If you call `setContentView` twice in the same activity then the second one is a crash for sure! To avoid that delete the second call of `setContentView`. In order to show the value on screen then you need to have in your xml ui both a button and a textview to show the value when available. Set at the textview an id `android:id="@+id/thisismytextviewid"` and then call that textview from code instead of `TextView FCR = new TextView(this);` write `TextView FCR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thisismytextviewid);` that will work!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem!!!

It was about that I must have put the get intent in the oncreate() method...thanks for your help (madlymad)